# How to Camera in Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

I am working on an android app. i want to enable camera in it. I am using AVD2.2 Froyo.There is no option for camera support in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [This](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-camera-in-android-emulator/)  to enable camera in your Android Emulator...

Comment: I have tried this.But there is no option to camera support when i am adding new hardware